# FAA Chart Supplement Database

Tags: api, database, aviation

Has anyone found while delving into the NASR subscription or the d-TTP databases information on the ELA/SEC boundaries? I am wondering where the chart supplements get their data in the upper right margin of each airport on which sectional and ELA they can be found? The API and ADDS the FAA has seems to be incomplete/under construction. The data seems to be there in the tables, but not human readable and the AIXD viewers are greek to me. Anyone else having better luck at extracting useful information for app design?

Comment: can you provide some links/more information please?